# Elementor Header doesn't appear in WooCommerce pages

Tags: woocommerce, header, hook-woocommerce, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a header using the plugin Elementor Header & Footer Builder.
The header is applied to all pages perfectly, but all pages related to WooCommerce have the old header.
I don't know how to solve this issue.

Is there is some setting anywhere or code to fix that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTIwV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Nn2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I found a selection in the header plugin in the WordPress editor form not in the elementor display role it was selected to display to all pages, solved after changing to the entire site.